# Parsing xml with python, many similar attributes

Tags: python, xml, parsing, nested, attributes

Good day, dear developers, I need to parse XML file like this:
(using  xml.etree.ElementTree python module)

```
<level1>
   <level2 id="1">
      <level3>
        <level4 id="1">name1</foobar>
        <level4 id="2">name2</foobar>
     </level3>
   </level2>
</level1>
```

I've got dozens of **level4** items, how can i get specific ones? If i need to get just name2 or id=2 attribute what should i do?

I use this code to take the **level4** item at the moment.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

root = source.findall('.//level4')
counter = 0

for elem in root:
    counter +=1
    if counter = 2:
        id = elem.get('Id')
```

But what if i need many level1-3 items and some of them don't have **name1** item?
The loop won't work properly then. Thank you in advance